# Несколько тяжелых методов средствами UniRx

Tags: c#, unity3d, многопоточность

Использую ассет **UniRx** для того чтобы что то считать в других потоках. Использовал [эту вот](https://h.amazingsoftworks.com/ru/company/nix/blog/268781/) статью, в ней в разделе "[Пример обработки сложных методов](https://h.amazingsoftworks.com/ru/company/nix/blog/268781/#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2)" написано как выполнять несколько тяжеловесных задач в разных потоках.

Так вот я пытаюсь обработать матрицу по кускам, по потоку на каждый блок, поделив ее 7х7, для примера просто вывожу **Debug.Log()**:

```
/// Кол-ва блоков
Vector2Int size = new Vector2Int(7, 7);

/// Храним методы
System.IObservable<Unit>[] loadThreads = 
    new System.IObservable<Unit>[size.x * size.y];

for (int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
    {
        loadThreads[x * size.x + y] = Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            Debug.Log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);

            // такой же эффект
            //int x1 = x, y1 = y;
            //Debug.Log("x: " + x1 + " y: " + y1);

            return;
        });
    }

/// Работаем
Observable.WhenAll(loadThreads).
    ObserveOnMainThread().Subscribe(result =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Finish");
    });
```

Что в итоге дает эффект как будто x и y передались ссылками и у меня везде конечные индексы + 1, как будто цикл кончился, в конце прибавил еще один индекс и в итоге другой поток обращается в память где эти x и y с циклов и видит там 7-рки...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я в многопоточности очень слаб, помогите подскажите как правильно реализовать решение?

PS: Возможно нужно решать задачу другими средствами? Мне в голову пришло сразу то, как в майнкрафте карта генерится по кругу, может нужно какую то Queue с индексами? Я не понимаю, пните хотя бы меня в нужную сторону мысления

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классика, решается кешированием переменных. Делегат захватывает именно ссылки, поэтому очень простой фикс нужен.

```
int x1 = x, y1 = y;
loadThreads[x * size.x + y] = Observable.Start(() =>
{
    Debug.Log("x: " + x1 + " y: " + y1);
});
```

То есть мысль верная была, но вы это делали в делегате, а надо было за его пределами.

Comment: Спасибо, работает) Ну да это логично теперь